# Can I change the location of SvelteKit's 'static' directory?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

The [SvelteKit documentation for `static`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/project-structure#project-files-static) doesn't mention the directory is configurable.

Note I am not using a static site generator, but rather the default (`adapter-auto`). My `svelte.config.js` looks like this:

```
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-auto";

import { vitePreprocess } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
  // for more information about preprocessors
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

  kit: {
    // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
    // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
    // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
    adapter: adapter(),
  },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be [`kit.files.assets`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#files).

Note that very few files should actually be in there, mainly "well known" ones with a fixed path/name like `robots.txt`. Most things should just be [imported](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url) in the components, that way the files will be emitted as build assets, including a hash that helps with cache invalidation.